# How to restore the local drive "C:\" to it's default permissions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, administrator, user

I changed my permissions on local drive c:\ and now many applications/system things not working properly. i was wondering how can I restore How to restore the local drive "C:" to it's default permissions? and it's all contains/sub folder/sub files?

Comment: Easiest might be to reinstall Windows from ISO, keeping files; *if* it works. That said, make a disk image first, in case you need to back out.

Comment: “I was wondering how can I restore How to restore the local drive "C:" to it's default permissions?” - Reinstall Windows. I suggest NOT modifying the permissions on your entire system disk in the future. The default permissions are required and are set the way they are for a reason

Comment: Try to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @ramhound learnt that the hard way,

Comment: Will an image restore fix the issue? Because my windows is stuck for the past two hours on system restore is initilizaing

Comment: Tried every solution possible, Only hard reset fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To reset permissions for the folder: `icacls C:\ /reset`

To reset permissions for the folder, its files, and subfolders: `icacls C:\ /reset /t /c /l`

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/939036/how-to-set-c-drive-with-default-permission)